# Does GoogleAppEngine provide an API to monitor the resource usage for Java?

Tags: google-app-engine

Does GoogleAppEngine provide an API to monitor the CPU and memory usage for Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the online control panel. It's all there.

Go to "instances" to see stats for each running instance.

But an API (now I re-read your question), I don't believe so.

Appstats might give you some of what you are after however.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't.

You might be able to use the logs API to pull logs, parse them, and figure out the CPU usage on various instances.

No way you can get memory usage through an API though.